# ALC892 low quality, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, realtek

I'm having an issue with my sound card. I decided to (finally) leave windows and use Ubuntu, but when I'm hearing music with 100% volume, the music sound distorted. It's not the headphones, in windows they were working perfectly. I've tried to install realtek drivers but they are for 3.0 kernel. Any idea? thank you!

**Edit:** I also tried with equalizers and others music players but its' the same, when I pass 85% volume, the sound starts cracking.